# Expression Engine SimpleXmlIterator broken

Tags: php, xml, expressionengine

this is my first question, which I can't figure out how to make relevant to other people as per the guidelines. I suppose just a question at the end as to whether a noob should ever attempt to meddle with code they don't fully understand.

My site depends on an xml database generated elsewhere which is spliced into site-specific format, set up by the original developer. The system generating the database changed a tag from "contact" to "person", breaking the data formula for the splicing. (Grr.)

I *thought* I had fixed it, because I changed the tag in the receiving file, but the splicer has just stopped completely. (Basically, I don’t really know enough about the site/coding to have attempted to make these changes. But I thought I could get away with it!)

This is what I understand happens:
1. every night we send an xml file into folder
2. a php file reformats the raw xml with SimpleXmlIterator.
3. that sends the reformatted file to a staging.sql file.
4. that sends it to the right place for the site to load it nightly.

Step 4 is still happening, but the site is using the same data over and over. The new data is just not making it through step 2 and 3.

This is what I did (I just commented out the original code. I'm "SOC"):

```
$authors = array();
foreach ($author_array as $arr) {

  $bio = ($arr['copy_biography']) ? nl2br(htmlspecialchars($arr['copy_biography'], ENT_QUOTES)) : '';

  // SOC changed $author_title = $arr['contact_first_name'] .' '. $arr['contact_surname'];
  $author_title = $arr['person_first_name'] .' '. $arr['person_surname'];
  $authors[] = array(
    'title'     => $author_title,
    'author_id' => $arr['id'],
    // SOC changed from this to the below 'fname'     => $arr['contact_first_name'],
    'fname'     => $arr['person_first_name'],
    // SOC changed from this to the below 'lname'     => $arr['contact_surname'],
    'lname'     => $arr['person_surname'],
    // SOC ditto 'website'   => $arr['contact_web_page'],
    'website'   => $arr['person_web_page'],
    'bio'       => $bio,
    // SOC ditto 'twitter'   => $arr['contact_fax']
    'twitter'   => $arr['person_fax']
  );
}

$authors = generate_valid_xml_from_array($authors);
$authors_xml = '/var/www/hotkeybooks/biblio/authors_import.xml';
$authorfile = fopen($authors_xml,'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($authorfile,$authors);
fclose($authorfile);
//make the files readable
exec('chmod 444 /var/www/hotkeybooks/biblio/*.xml');
```

I also changed “contact” to “person” the staging.sql and the staging.tgz.

```
-- ----------------------------
--  Records of `exp_dd_doc_sections`
-- ----------------------------
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO `exp_dd_doc_sections` VALUES (…….<td>contact_first_name, contact_surname</td>\n         <td>Text Input</td>\n           <td>Would enter author full name, this field would only be used for admin purposes.</td>\n          <td>y</td>\n        </tr>\n     <tr>\n          <td>Author Biblio ID</td>\n         <td>author_biblio_id</td>\n         <td>id</td>\n           <td>Text Input</td>\n           <td>Used for relationship building and reference only</td>\n            <td></td>\n     </tr>\n     <tr>\n          <td>Author First Name</td>\n            <td>author_fname</td>\n         <td>contact_first_name</td>\n           <td>Text Input</td>\n           <td></td>\n         <td></td>\n     </tr>\n     <tr>\n          <td>Author Last Name</td>\n         <td>author_lname</td>\n         <td>contact_surname</td>\n          <td>Text Input</td>\n           <td></td>\n         <td></td>\n     </tr>\n ………)
```

Does anyone know which bit of what I did broke the system, and what I can do to restore it?
I have tried overwriting my changes with the original files, but that hasn’t helped.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need some basic troubleshooting.

Perhaps your parsing is working correctly but the transfer between the various locations is failing due to file permissions or something.

Working backwards:

Can you confirm that the file that is transferred in step 4 is a new file?  Does it have the expected modified date?  Does it have the expected data?

Can you confirm that the file in step 3 staging.sql is a new file with the expected modified date?  Does it have the expected data?

Can you confirm that the file created in step 2 is a new file with the expected date and data?

Do you seeing anything in your error log to suggest that anything in the script has failed?

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. Hrm.. This is clearly not the place to reply.

Comment: Okay, maybe it is! I just can't hit return.

I'm working on a thorough reply at the moment.

Comment: I can't figure out how to include an image in this comment box. I can see that the raw data goes in where it is supposed to. But I can see that the xml.php file that is supposed to be generated hasn't been. I don't know how to see my error log. I see the files just looking at the server through Filezilla.

Comment: I don't think you can add images to comment boxes; but you can update your question.  The apache error log could be literally anywhere but it most often here: `/var/log/httpd/yourdomin.com/error.log`.  Your script does not refer to a file with name `xml.php`. Can you clarify?

Comment: I can't find my error log - or, I can find lots of error logs that are empty, but these are for mysql. The xml.php file is the one that I've made the changes to.

Comment: I've found an error log that says: [Sun May 04 07:21:44 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.11 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun May 04 20:31:53 2014] [error] [client 95.211.191.66] client sent HTTP/1.1 request without hostname (see RFC2616 section 14.23): /w00tw00t.at.ISC.SANS.DFind:)